# scalar custom loss function in keras for end-to-end time series prediction resulting in NaN loss and predictions

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, nan, autoencoder, loss-function

I am working on a denoising autoencoder for audio, feeding raw time-series audio to the network and receiving time-series audio as output from the network. The `mean_square_error` loss objective function returns values of shape `(batch_size, audio_sequence_length)`, which (I hope I understood correctly) is further processed by Keras internally to reach the final single-valued loss used for backprop by computing the mean over time bins and batches.

My current efforts are focused on creating a custom loss function using signal power instead of the error of individual samples, returning values of shape `(batch_size, )`. The model compiles nicely but returns only NaN loss at training time. Trying to predict anything using such a model results in output vectors consisting of NaN as well.

This is the loss function:

```
def SI_SNR(yTrue,yPred):
     yTarget = K.batch_dot(yTrue,yPred,axes=0)      
     yTarget = K.batch_dot(yTrue,yTarget,axes=None)
     yNorm = K.batch_dot(yTrue,yTrue, axes = 0)
     yTarget = yTarget/yNorm
     eNoise = yPred - yTarget
     losses = -(10.*K.log(K.batch_dot(yTarget,yTarget,axes=0)/
               K.batch_dot(eNoise,eNoise,axes=0))/K.log(10.))
     return K.reshape(losses,([-1]))
```

When using the function on actual numbers (either using a subset of the training data or randomly filled arrays) I do get non NaN results:

```
x=K.variable(np.random.rand(8,1024,1))
y=K.variable(np.random.rand(8,1024,1))
K.eval(SI_SNR(y,x))
```

Is the training behavior due to the shape of the loss or is there perhaps some other problem with the internal structure of the loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: the output shape of the cost was not the issue. Tested this hypothesis using a different (dummy) loss:

```
def meanMSE(yTrue,yPred):
     return K.mean(mean_squared_error(yTrue,yPred),axis=1)
```

If `yPred` is a vector of zeros, the previous cost function has Div0 issues, using `backend.clip` and modifying the function slightly, the problem is resolved:

```
def SDR(yTrue,yPred):
     return(K.batch_dot(yPred,yPred,axes=1)/
             K.clip(K.square(K.batch_dot(yPred,yTrue,axes=1)),1e-7,1e12))
```